# Loopback: Create dynamic properties for model instance

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

For example I have a loopback model name `Event` and it has 2 properties like this:

```
...
"properties": {
  "name": {
    "type": "string",
    "required": true
  },
  "end": {
    "type": "date",
    "required": false
  }
}...
```

How can I add a dynamic property name `status` with logic like this:

```
if (now() > this.end) {
  this.status = 'end';
} else {
  this.status = 'running';
}
```

Also I want to have `status` in those JSON responses for Loopback REST API as well. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the required property the `ctx` in the remote hook or the operation hook, the property will be added to the model and saved to the database.

Using remote hook,

```
Event.beforeRemote('*', (ctx, modelInstance, next) => {
    ctx.req.body.propertyName = propertyValue;
    ...
    next();
});
```

Here, * can be any action for any endpoint. Refer [this](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html#wildcards) for more details.

Using Operation hook,

```
Event.observe('before save', (ctx, next) => {
   //for insert, full update
   if(ctx.instance) {
       ctx.instance.propertyName = propertyValue;
       ...
       return next();
   } 
   // for partial update
   else if(ctx.data) { 
       ctx.data.propertyName = propertyValue;
       ...
       return next();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is with [remote hooks](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html) and simply add the property to the result set if applicable.  To paraphrase the documentation:

```
Event.afterRemote('**', function (ctx, user, next) {
  const now = new Date();
  if(ctx.result) {
    if(Array.isArray(ctx.result)) {
      ctx.result.forEach(function (result) {
        result.status = now > result.end ? 'end' : 'running';
      });
    } else {
      result.status = now > result.end ? 'end' : 'running';
    }
  }

  next();
});
```